# how to find thhe eddsa for updating my spl-token

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, metaplex-js

I'm looking for a way to update my eddsa variable, am using metaplex, am new to updating a token in using metaplex.

there is my code

> 

```
`import * as mpl from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata"
import {
    updateV1,
    fetchMetadataFromSeeds,
} from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'
import  { PublicKey,  } from "@solana/web3.js"
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const fs = require('fs');

async function main() {
    const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./hfbiuv34h43fbu43igf9348bcdbcu34u34uh.json')));
    const payer = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);

    const METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ADDRESS = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
    const metaplexProgramPublicKey = new PublicKey(METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ADDRESS);
    // Connect to Solana cluster
    const programsObject = {
        metaplex: metaplexProgramPublicKey,
        // Add other programs as needed
    };
    const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));
    
    const umi = {
        connection: connection,
        programs: {
            metaplex: metaplexProgramPublicKey,
        },
        eddsa: null,
        identity: payer, 
        payer: payer
    };

    const mint = new web3.PublicKey('hfbiuv34h43fbu43igf9348bcdbcu34u34uh');
    const updateAuthority = payer.publicKey; 

    const newMetadata = {
         name: "test",
         symbol: "TSA",
         uri: "https://deufuerf/metadata.json", 
     };

    // Create a Metadata object
    const initialMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint });

    // Update the metadata
    await updateV1(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: updateAuthority,
        data: { ...initialMetadata, newMetadata },
        primarySaleHappened: true,
        isMutable: true,
        // Add other attributes you want to update
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

main().catch(console.error);`
```